# Sematic UI override bootstrap page styling in react nextjs projet

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap, semantic-ui-react

I'm working on an update of an existing project, and the whole project uses **Bootstrap** , and the only place where I would like to replace **bootstrap** by **semantic UI** is in components where I defined list items.

Here is what i've done :

1 - I've followed the following guide : [Get Started with Semantic UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage/) to install **React semantic UI**

2 - And in my header tag, i've place the semantic UI cdn before bootstrap

Note : I've use the [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) for bootstrap

The **semantic UI** components render as expected , but the only problem is that the whole pages are now using **semantic UI** even my form field that i've created with bootstrap.
Where can the problem come from?

Comment: You can use the cdn of Semantic UI in your public index.html file instead of installing it for your whole react application

Comment: Yes,but i'll not be able to use the **semantic ui** react components.

Answer (score 0):

There can (will) be a lot of conflicts between SUIR and bootstrap. You probably shouldn't import the whole package. Instead install only needed modules. You can find a list of individual ones [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui)

Certain elements in both packages share similar naming patterns, so there will be namespace conflicts. You can rename semantic element keywords in `semantic.js` and `semantic.css`.